# creating a separate docker-compose configuration for production and development

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, container-image

I have a `docker-compose` setup for development, and I need to replicate the same file for production or staging.

Currently, aside from `volumes` `ports` and `environment` I am not quite sure what settings "may need" to be changed for production/environment.

To clarify:

- I have to change `volumes`, because I usually mount a USB drive to my docker container ex: `d:/var/www`
- The issue with `ports` is, because there may be other services that use port 80 on my local machine, so I may need to change that.
- `environment` is of course, different for prod/dev .. (mainly authentication and database access)

Any more tips would be nice to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact list would depend on your environment/ops team requirements, but this is what seems to be useful besides ports/existing volumes:

**Networks**

The default network might not work for your prod environment. 
As an example, your ops team might decide to put nginx/php-fpm/mariadb on different networks like in the following example (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) or even use a pre-existing network

**Mysql configs**

They usually reside in a separate dir i.e. `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my.cnf.d`. 
These configs are likely to be different between prod/dev.
Can’t see it in your volumes paths

**Php-fpm7**

Haven’t worked with `php-fpm7`, but in `php-fpm5` it also had a different folder with config files (`/etc/php-fpm.conf` and `/etc/php-fpm.d`) that is missing in your volumes. These files are also likely to differ once your handle even a moderate load (you’ll need to configure number of workers/timeouts etc)

**Nginx**

Same as for `php-fpm`, ssl settings/hostnames/domains configurations are likely to be different

**Logging**

Think on what logging driver might fit your needs best.
From [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/):

> Docker includes multiple logging mechanisms to help you get
>   information from running containers and services. These mechanisms are
>   called logging drivers.

You can easily configure it in docker-compose, here's an example bring up a dedicated `fluentd` container for logging:

```
version: "3"

services:
  randolog:
    image: golang
    command: go run /usr/src/randolog/main.go
    volumes:
      - ./randolog/:/usr/src/randolog/
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        fluentd-address: "localhost:24224"
        tag: "docker.{{.ID}}"

  fluentd:
    build:
      context: ./fluentd/
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the [Use Compose in production
 documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#modify-your-compose-file-for-production):

> You probably need to make changes to your app configuration to make it
>   ready for production. These changes may include:
>
> - Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside
> - Binding to different ports on the host
> - Setting environment variables differently, such as when you need to    decrease the verbosity of logging, or to enable email sending)
> - Specifying a restart policy like `restart: always` to avoid downtime
> - Adding extra services such as a log aggregator

Comment: I have read the docs, point two and five are a little vague and the doc is far from comprehsive, that is why I asked the question